# mongodbを使っているwebアプリでエラーが出る

Tags: node.js, mongodb

こんにちは

いま、mongodb atlasを使ってwebアプリの試作をしているのですが

```
C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:184
            throw new error_1.MongoInvalidArgumentError('The callback form of this helper has been removed.');
            ^

MongoInvalidArgumentError: The callback form of this helper has been removed.
    at Db.collection (C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:184:19)
    at C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\routes\page_a.js:20:12
    at C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:532:9
    at C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:130:17
    at connectCallback (C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:38:9)    
    at C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:89:9
    at C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:231:25
    at C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:272:25
    at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:363:9)    
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\sgiga\Project\orangewebsite\express-gen-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:9)
```

このようなエラーが出ました
あるサイトを見ながらやっているのでコードの間違いはないと思いますが、、、
どこかおかしな部分があれば教えてください

補足:
コードが長いのとファイルが多いのでリポジトリのURLを載せます
https://github.com/minato37103710/orangeweb.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

古いタイプのmongooseの書き方をやってたみたいで、mongooseの公式サイトにあるquick startで試したらできました